# Jumping distance due to X velocity

Tags: java, jumping

I would just like to know if there is a way to work out the distance of a jump depending on how fast the player is going. For example if the player has a velocity X of 10 and he presses the jump button he should jump further than if his X velocity was, say 4.

I have a working jump mechanic that when the jump button is pressed the velocity is set to a predefined value like -10; Then slowly gravity brings it down but I want it to feel more realistic by applying the jump distance according to his speed

Any way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using velocities for this, the "jump distance" will be handled automatically. The distance on the X axis traveled during the jump is the product of the time in the air, and the X axis velocity. Say your jump takes one second to complete. If your character is traveling at 10 units per second on the X axis, during that one second jump, they will have traveled 10 units. If their speed is 4 units per second on the X axis, they will have traveled 4 units during the jump.

If you're experiencing otherwise, make sure you're maintaining the X velocity when changing your Y velocity for the jump.